# How to call javascript function defined in another file from HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a website, but when I try to call a JavaScript function defined in another file from my HTML code I get the following error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: fetchConfs is not defined at admin.html:46

I did import the script in the `<head>` portion of the HTML, but for some reason, I am still getting the error.

admin.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bundle.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.3/firebase.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <title>Dilo+</title>
</head>
<header class="header">
    <img src="logo.png">
    <p>Sobreviviendo a lo imposible</p>
</header>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "",
            authDomain: "dilo-mas.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://dilo-mas.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "dilo-mas",
            storageBucket: "",
            messagingSenderId: ""
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        initApp = function () {
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
                if (user) {
                    var email = user.email;
                    user.getIdToken().then(function (accessToken) {
                        document.getElementById("greeter").textContent = "Hola " + email;
                    });
                } else {
                    window.location.href = '/login.html'
                }
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        };
        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            initApp()
            document.getElementById("logout").onclick = function logout() {
                firebase.auth().signOut().then(function () { window.location.href = '/login.html' });
            }
            var confs = fetchConfs();
        });
    </script>
    <h1 id="greeter">Error, inicia sesión para continuar</h1>
    <button class="mdc-button foo-button" id="logout" style="float: right;">
        Cerrar Sesión
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js (This file is compiled to bundle.js using webpacks before deploying):

```
import {MDCRipple} from '@material/ripple/index';
import { MDCTextField } from '@material/textfield';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/firebase-auth';

const ripple = new MDCRipple(document.querySelector('.foo-button'));

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "dilo-mas.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://dilo-mas.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "dilo-mas",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

document.getElementById("tbut").onclick = function submitForm() {
    var date = Date.now().toString()
    var x = document.getElementById("conf").value;
    firebase.firestore().collection("confesiones").doc(date).set({
        conf: x
    })
        .then(function () {
            console.log("Document successfully written!");
            var y = document.getElementById("conf").value;
            console.log("input " + x)
            alert("Exito");
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
            alert("Error envíando tu confesión")
        });
    document.getElementById("conf").reset();
}

function fetchConfs() {
    var confs = db.collection("confesiones").where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "!=", "root").get();
    return confs;
}
```

I already tried assigning `fetchConfs()` to the window object or to a global variable, but I'm still getting the same error.

Note: I am using webpacks and other npm plugins to compile js and sass code to static files for deployment.

Comment: Just assign `fetchConfs` to `window`?

Comment: from what little knowledge I have about webpack and compilers etc, I do know that a built file in JS often does not maintain the naming scheme. So it might be defined in your code but webpack may export it as `_fetchConfs` or something along those lines. Perhaps look at the compiled output and see what you can find. if it still doesn't work, then you might want to try assigning the function to the window object.

Answer (score 0):

Scripts are run in the order that they are listed in `<head>`, then any in the body. If the function is in a script listed later, that function may not be defined yet when it is run.

To fix this, define `fetchConfs` earlier on.

Comment: The script is imported before the function is called. The script is the first one listed in the head, the function is called in the body